# Moving labels off the pie chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mschart

I am trying to move the labels OFF of the pie chart using the canned chart control from VS2010 (mvc, ef and asp.net)

Here is my code to display the piechart.

```
  string xx = activePhysicianID;
  ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
  ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();
  XXXXX_MainEntities dbContext = new XXXXX_MainEntities();
  var results = dbContext.Payor.Where(rs => rs.PhysicianIdentity.Equals(xx));

  results.ToList().ForEach(rs => xValue.Add(rs.Identifier));
  results.ToList().ForEach(rs => yValue.Add(rs.Strength));

  var chart = new Chart(600, 300, ChartTheme.Blue);

  chart.AddSeries(chartType: "Pie", xValue: xValue, yValues: yValue);
  chart.AddTitle("Payor");
  chart.Write("png");

  return null;
```

The pie chart is rendered ok, but the labels are on the pie chart, and it is too hard to read.  I would like to labels placed off the chart with lines pointing to the segment.

thanks

Comment: Check this link http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=956

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
chart.Series["Pie"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
```